# How to overlay layouts?

Tags: android

I programmatically create the layout of my view:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsDummy = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, this.optimalCenterPadding);
layoutParamsDummy.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDummy = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
relativeLayoutDummy.setId(DUMMY_ID);
relativeLayoutDummy.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_background));
relativeLayoutDummy.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsDummy);

relativeLayoutCenter.addView(relativeLayoutDummy);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageViewCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParamsImageViewCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layoutParamsImageViewCenter.setMargins(0, this.optimalCenterBackgroundPadding, 0, 0);

this.imageViewCenter = new ImageView(this.getContext());
this.imageViewCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageViewCenter);
this.imageViewCenter.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getContext(), Paths.IMAGE_BACKGROUND_POWER));
this.imageViewCenter.setBackground(null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageButtonCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParamsImageButtonCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layoutParamsImageButtonCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, DUMMY_ID);

this.imageButtonCenter = new ImageButton(this.getContext());
this.imageButtonCenter.setId(CENTER_ID);
this.imageButtonCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageButtonCenter);
this.imageButtonCenter.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getContext(), Paths.IMAGE_POWER));
this.imageButtonCenter.setBackground(null);
this.imageButtonCenter.setOnDragListener(new DropTargetOnDragListener());
```

I have to do it programmatically because i use a custom circular layout.
What i have now is the following:

[image]

Two circles with the bigger circle below the smaller one. What i want to have is the following:

[image]

the bigger circle should be exactly under the smaller circle that means i want the smaller circle to overlay the bigger circle. It is a very hard task to calculate the correct position for working on every screen size and density and that leads me to the following question:

**Can i place a layout exactly under another layout?**

I cant just set the background of the imagebutton or something like that because the green, smaller circle is the drop area for other buttons. the bigger circle should not trigger the drop event.

I also cant work with margins because i dynamically place buttons around the green, smaller circle. I tried margins but they completly screwed up the positioning of these buttons.

Comment: can you use a FrameLayout?

Comment: "I have to do it programmatically because i use a custom circular layout." You know you can use a custom view through xml layotus right?

Comment: yes i know that. but not possible in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT` instead of RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL.

Also, do you add your imageViewCenter and imageButtonCenter to your relativeLayoutDummy or relativeLayoutCenter? I see a possible problem in line `layoutParamsImageButtonCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, DUMMY_ID);` which means, that DUMMY_ID layout will be positioned (vertically) under imageButtonCenter, it will not overlay it.

Comment: unfortunately i cant do that because the vertical centralization wouldnt fit.

Comment: Please, see my updated answer and check whether you add your imageview and imagebutton into correct layout.

Comment: yes thats the current way for me to positionate the views. it is working for one screen but on another screen with anohter resolution it does not fit. that is why im asking for just a simple overlay function ^^